# Shechita only during the times of the Beis Hamikdash

Tags: talmud-gemara, kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Can someone point me to where in the Talmud there’s an opinion that shechita is only required during the times of the Beis Hamikdash?

Comment: Hi, there! Where'd you hear about this opinion? (I'm not familiar with any opinion like that, but then again I'm no great scholar.) Adding more information and background to your question will make it easier for others to help you find an answer. Good luck, and I hope you can find what you're looking for! :-)

Comment: I heard about this opinion at https://learn.oheltorah.com/t/rabeinu-tam-cheese/5405 where it's mentioned it was a Tanna, but wasn't specified who or a citation.

Comment: Maybe Chullin 16b-17a? שבתחלה נאסר להם בשר תאוה משנכנסו לארץ הותר להם בשר תאוה  and discussion